# Best way to return a list of a particular property from a list with objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Having this:

```
public class TableMeta
{
    public string Name;
    public int TimeToLive;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    public List<String> getTableNameList(List<TableMeta> dlist)
    {
        List<String> tnlist = new List<String>();
        foreach (TableMeta meta in dlist)
        {
            tnlist.Add(meta.Name);
        }
        return tnlist;
    }
```

This is, creating a list based on an attribute from a custom class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, use LINQ.

```
return dlist.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

This will, as it says, select all the names and return them as a list.